Why ceil rounds up in this situation?
var_dump(ceil((float) 55));
// float(55)

var_dump(ceil(55.0));
// float(55)

var_dump(ceil(22 / 40 * 100));
// float(56)

Why did the first two examples return 55, while the third example returned 56? Can you explain the difference in behavior?
for more clarity:
22 / 40 * 100 = 55
I have tried this examples with PHP 7.4 and 8.1.

"for more clarity: 22 / 40 * 100 = 55" ... or is it? Try var_dump(22 / 40 * 100); and see what it says. More details: Is floating-point math broken?

Try printf("%.18f",22/40) and you get 0.550000000000000044. This is a general floating point issue, because numbers like 0.55 are binary-rounded to the next existing number. If you change the expression to 100*22/40 you get 55.

If you need the preceision, use bcmath. https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php
